# Подскажите, почему не срабатывает замена подстроки?

Tags: javascript

Задача - разделить произвольный текст и убрать лишние возможные символы, такие как "." или например ",". Как это сделать? У меня в консоли сработало, а вот в целом коде не работает. И как проверить на все возможные знаки? На каждый писать отдельную строку? Ведь может еще и "!" быть, например.

```
var text = prompt('Введите любой произвольный текст', 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника');
var textArr = text.split(' ');
for (i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
    textArr[i].replace(',', '');
};
```

Comment: @Grundy, ну какой дубликат, если, судя по вопросу, ему вообще нужен вот такой ответ: `var textArr = text.split(/[\s,]+/).filter(Boolean);` и без всяких циклов и замен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там про replace, и тут про replace - все ок :-) Ну и в таком случае больше похоже на `.match(/[а-я]+/gi)` а не на split :)

Comment: @Grundy, а как же `a-z`?) И у match ещё обычно случай с null мешается)

Comment: @Qwertiy, это для примера было :-)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что надо читать [описание функции String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - этот метод не меняет вызывающую строку, а возвращает новую, после замен.

Для замены используйте присваивание.

```
var text = prompt('Введите любой произвольный текст', 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника');
var textArr = text.split(' ');
for (i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
    textArr[i] = textArr[i].replace(',', '');
};
```

Comment: а как же тогда заменить?

Comment: @PolonskiyP дополнил ответ, надо заменять старое значение в массиве новым, которое вернет replace.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!)

Comment: `.replace(',', '')` - заменяет только первую запятую.

Comment: @PolonskiyP, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него. Но вообще, подозреваю, что тебе вместо всего этого надо `var textArr = text.split(/[\s,]+/).filter(Boolean);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = prompt('Введите любой произвольный текст', 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника');
var textArr = text.replace(',', '').split(' ');
```

**UPD:**

```
var text = prompt('Введите любой произвольный текст', 'Футбол это игра, целью которой является забить мяч в ворота противника');
var textArr = text.replace(/[,!]/g, '').split(' ');
```

Comment: `.replace(',', '')` - заменяет только первую запятую.

Comment: Ну `.replace('/[,!]/g', '')`...

Comment: Не `'/[,!]/g'`, а просто `/[,!]/g`.